# angular2-chartjs: Multiple charts in single component?

Tags: angular

I'm using angular2-chartjs for charts in my Angular app following https://github.com/emn178/angular2-chartjs.
It works fine and I can add any single type chart available in the module.
However, I want 3 multiple type charts on the same page/component i.e. Pie, Line and Bar chart. I have searched for this and found like [How can I get multiple charts(bar and line) with ng2-charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886007/how-can-i-get-multiple-chartsbar-and-line-with-ng2-charts) but didn't work in my case as I'm using `<chart>` element, and mostly solutions are with `<canvas>` element and I guess that the version doesn't support.

Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you just use <chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart> 
three times with different types in your template?

Comment: Example: 
`<div id="pie-chart">
<chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart>
</div>
<div id="line-chart">
<chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart>
</div>
<div id="bar-chart">
<chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart>
</div>`

Comment: Options and Data can be different for each chart like 
pieChartData, pieChartOptions
lineChartData, lineChartOptions
barChartData, barChartOptions
These can the different properties in .ts file to use in different charts.

Comment: But how to differentiate or assign the ID in .ts file for every chart?

Comment: Well, I got it done.